# Any one know why this XHR request is not posting? Error 500

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I set up this XMLHttpRequest(); and it is showing error 500.

```html
<?php 
SESSION_start();

$balance = $_POST['public'];
$_SESSION['test'] = $balance;
```

```js
    var ne = 4;
  var params = 'public='+ne;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();


    xhr.open("POST", "url.php");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send(params);
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your XHR works fine. Your error is returned by the server running url.php.

A common issue is a bad .htaccess configuration, or your server is not ready and configured properly to interpret PHP.

Did you test browsing url.php normally? If POST requests are not being received, I don't see how GET requests would work either.

Comment: _"or the document is returning a 404 Not Found error"_ - They are explicitly saying that they get a 500 error, which they also shouldn't get if it was a CORS issue.

Comment: Thank you, for the help. I have a bunch of other php code running on the post page that I had believed was running correctly. Did a quick cut and just ran the post which posted just fine. Its been a long day lol.